# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 42 bytes)

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am retrieving record from MySQL table which return more than 0.2m number of rows per query, which obviously take lot of memory. In my case I have 8 GB of RAM on my system with 256 GB of SSD space. When I execute my page it returns the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 42 bytes) in D:\xampp\htdocs\classes\CRUD.php on line 84

Should I use threading instead of PHP loops over table rows?

Comment: This should be asked in [sf].

Comment: You should paginate your results to handle less of them at a time, also apparently your memory limit per thread is set to 132Mb in the php config. You could increase it

Comment: Write your code to we could help you. It is possible that it is something in that loop what causes memory exhaustion.

Comment: @peuh you are right, but here in my code i am not allowed to use pagination otherwise it is really a very good suggestion.

Comment: Why would you select such big amount of rows in php script ? Optimize the query by selecting only used fields or use "pagination".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Default php.ini memory_limit is 128 MB. You should either:

- Optimize your code to use a **normal amount of data**
- change memory_limit in php.ini to higher value which I do not recommend at all - with your approach you will hit this wall once again

Answer (score 8):

You can expand your memory from within your file with the following line of code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

Add this code to the top of your file and ahange 16M to be whatever you need it be and that should do it.

Comment: what about => ini_set('memory_limit','2G'); will it work? or there should be any other good idea?

Comment: You can go higher, but as Maciej Asembler said, it is not advised. My solution is a quick fix. Ideally, you need to streamline your application.

Comment: You should also check if you can invoke ini_set anyways.

Comment: In case anyone with laravel project wonder where to put it! If the code is executing in web page call, then you need to put it in index.php in the very first line after <?php starts. If the code is running from any artisan command like queue, then you need to add this in artisan file in same position as told before.....

Comment: Hi @AbdulRahman, I am facing thesame problem like you. I have increased to 500MB but still not enough. How did you finally solve the issue in an effective manner ?

Comment: @FokwaBest i changed my code style- I send the request with json and returned the json encoded array of values only. which did two things for me: 1- Increased the speed of the response 2- minimized the size of the response from huge size to some MBs which was the actual requirement and solution for me. i will advise you to not increase the size of the memory limit as it is not the solution of the problem.