# Laravel getting error while uploading large file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-5.6

I am trying to upload software installation file (.exe) in my site.When I am trying to upload file like 5 mb or 10 mb, I don't get any error.But while trying to upload large file,size of 45/50mb,I am getting this error

`(1/1) FatalThrowableError`

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null
```

I have changed my php.ini like this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 900M
```

Here is my file upload form

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    Product name:
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br /><br />
    Files :
    <br />
    <input type="file" name="pdf" multiple />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function google(Request $request){

            $file = $request->file('pdf');
            $destinationPath = 'uploads';
            $file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());

}
```

Update:

I have increased `post_max_size` greater than `upload_max_filesize`.But now getting this error

```
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 62973720 bytes)
in MediaFileUpload.php (line 246)
```

Comment: Have you changed 'post_max_size' in your php.ini to something higher than the accepted file size?

Comment: You're not getting the image data. Perform some kind of validation before executing that code.

Comment: I have  changed 'post_max_size' in my php.ini to  higher than the accepted file size.Now I am getting this error  (1/1) FatalErrorException
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 62973720 bytes)
in MediaFileUpload.php (line 246)

Comment: So increase memory as well

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: what is the new value of `post_max_size`?

Comment: post_max_size = 950M

upload_max_filesize = 800M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default php.ini memory_limit is 128 MB. You should either:

- Optimize your code to use a normal amount of data
- change **memory_limit** in php.ini to higher value which I do not
  recommend at all - with your approach you will hit this wall once
  again

You should refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36999610/6600883). I would recommend you monitor your application and see if there is a potential memory leak and optimize your code.

One of the key things you need to remember with standard file uploading, is that your server needs to handle the file, hints why it takes up a lot of memory.

Hopefully that helps you on the right path.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17233643)

Comment: Added answer here.

Answer (score 1):

In php.ini increase 'memory_limit'